# Pick 4 values in an array with a random starter index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random

**My array looke like :**

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
```

**So I random starter point (index) like :**

```
var start = getRandomInt(0,5);
function getRandomInt (min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

**For example :**

if `start` is `0`, so return `0,1,2,3`

if `start` is `1`, so return `1,2,3,4`

if `start` is `2`, so return `2,3,4,5`

if `start` is `3`, so return `3,4,5,0`

if `start` is `4`, so return `4,5,0,1`

if `start` is `5`, so return `5,0,1,2`

Just random a start index so loop that array

I wonder any easy way to do this ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/2tSdb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is to move from the last index back to 0, which you can do with the modulo operation. You should do something similar to the following:

```
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

var NUM_VALUES = 4; // Amount of values to take
var start = 3; // Replace with getRandomInt function
var values = [];

for(var i = start, j = 0; j < NUM_VALUES; j++, i = (i+1) % data.length) {
  values.push(data[i]);
}

console.log(values); // [ 3, 4, 5, 0 ]
```

Variable `i` contains the current index of the Array we are going to access. It is initialized to `start` like you want. The variable `j` is only there to make sure we grab the number of values you want, `4` in this case. As you can see, `j` is incremented by 1 after each loop and we keep going until it is equal to `NUM_VALUES`. Nothing fancy there.

Variable `i` is also incremented by 1 (`i = i+1`), but we apply the modulo operation after that in order to keep the resulting number between `0` and `data.length-1`. Modulo simply results in the remainder after integer division, so `6 % 4` would be `2`, `6 % 6` would be `0`, etc. This is done so the index can never be higher than the last index. When `i` hits `6` here, the modulo would push it back to `0` like we want.

Comment: thanks so much but  --- > http://jsfiddle.net/2tSdb/1/ , Why sometime `undefined` ?

Comment: @l2aelba Was your random number higher than the last index? You can add a modulo to `start` as well, but perhaps then you should fix your random function :)

Comment: Yeah I saw, you called your random function with `0, len`, but that should have been `0, len-1` :).

Comment: If you can expan that `(var i = start, j = 0; j < NUM_VALUES; j++, i = (i+1) % data.length)` gonna help me and another so much :D

Comment: @l2aelba I added a bit of explanation to my answer above.